# Why does multi-class classification fails with sigmoid?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function, multiclass-classification, activation-function

MNIST trained with Sigmoid fails while Softmax works fine

I am trying to investigate how different activation affects the final results, so I implemented a simple net for MNIST with PyTorch.

I am using NLLLoss (Negative log likelihood) as it implements Cross Entropy Loss when used with softmax.

When I have softmax as activation of the last layer, it works great.
But when I used sigmoid instead, I noticed that things fall apart

Here is my network code

```
def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 80)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.XXXX(x)
```

where XXXX is the activation function

both Sigmoid and Softmax output values between (0, 1).
Yes Softmax guarantees the sum of 1 but I am not sure if this answers why the training fails with Sigmoid.
Is there any detail I am not catching here?

Comment: sigmoid is notorious for Vanishing gradients , may be this is affecting your final results

Comment: Note that softmax actually reduces to sigmoid if there are only 2 classes. However, I can't understand how you are actually using sigmoid for multi-class classification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigmoid + crossentropy can be used for multilabel classification (assume a picture with a dog and a cat, you want the model to return "dog and cat"). It works when the classes aren't mutually exclusive or the samples contain more than one object that you want to recognize.

In your case MNIST has mutually exclusive classes and in each image there is only one number, so it is better to use logsoftmax + negative loglikelihood, which assume that the classes are mutually exclusive and there is only one correct label associated to the image.

So, you can't really expect to have that behavior from sigmoid.

Comment: what do you mean by mutually (exclusive)?

Comment: an image in MNIST cannot be both 2 and 5, it's either 2 or 5

Comment: Sigmoid + "binary" cross entropy is used for multilabel classification not sigmoid + cross entropy. right? your first line might be misleading

Comment: @BrandonLee crossentropy is valid for mulitclass, it just happened to be binary for your case.

Comment: @JibinMathew but isn't it dangerous to use sigmoid with CE as CE (not binary) has mutually exclusive assumption while sigmoid does not? I have experienced a collapse throughout my training and I thought it is caused by the difference in assumption.